# Select n rows randomly of matrix and vector with no repetition

Tags: r

I have a mat(1e6,34) and a vector vt(1e6). I'd like to get a mat2(1000,34) and a vector vt2(1000) where the 1000 rows are taken from the original matrix randomly.

I thought this would be easy in R but I didn't find a solution yet.

I could do

```
mat2 <- matrix(,ncol=34,nrow=1)
vt2 <- matrix(,ncol=1,nrow=1)
for (i in 1:1000) {
  i <- sample(1:1e6, 1)
  mat2 <- rbind(mat2,mat[i,])
  vt2 <- rbind(vt2,vt[i])
}
mat2 <- mat2[-1,]
vt2 <- vt2[-1,]
```

But I believe it can done in less lines, plus this does not ensure that I won't get repeated rows. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not make use of, say, `sample(1e6, 1000, FALSE)`?

Comment: Thanks! I should have thought of that

Comment: @AnandaMahto +1 if you convert to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a matrix named "mat" (`ncol = 34` and `nrow = 1e6`), you should be able to do what you want with:

```
mat[sample(1e6, 1000, FALSE), ]
```

A similar approach can be done with your vector, "vt" of length 1e6:

```
vt[sample(1e6, 1000, FALSE)]
```

---

Of course, if you want the same indices for the rows to extract *and* the vector position to extract, either:

- Store the result of `sample(1e6, 1000, FALSE)` as a separate vector and use that to subset.
- Use `set.seed(your-favorite-or-most-random-number)` before each call to `sample`, of course, using the same seed each time.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something in your question, but would this work?

```
sampleSubset<-sample(1:1e6, 1000) #defaults to replace = FALSE
mat2<-mat[sampleSubset, ]    #take the randomly selected rows
vect2<-vect[sampleSubset]    #take the corresponding vector entries
```

Comment: Accept Ananda's if he posts, he got it first!